# Powershell: How do I execute multiple txt files on SQL Server

Tags: t-sql, powershell, automation

I'm slowly learning to utilize Powershell and as a newbie please be easy on me. I created a Powershell script that would generate an insert statement from a number of excel files and save it into individual text files. How could I utilize Powershell to execute the text files on SQL Server?

Comment: Is powershell required? It's achievable via windows command line easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment was indeed very helpful. Since I don't have GO Statements on my txt files I made use of this method which I derived from yours @ShawnMelton

```
#Get list of files
$Files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\Test\*.txt'


try {
    $Filename = $File.BaseName 

    foreach ($file in $files) {

    Invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance "ServerName" -Database "Test" -InputFile $file -ErrorAction Stop 
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "EXECUTED SuCCESSFULLY: " $filename 
    Move-Item $File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Test\Executed"
 }
}
catch {
 Write-Host -ForegroundColor RED "FAILED TO EXECUTE: " $filename
}
```

To avoid confusion I transferred all successfully executed files on a seperate folder. Therefore all unexecuted and failed to execute script would be left on the main folder.

Answer (score 2):

It will be based on the queries you have in the text files. If they have the `GO` transaction terminator, then you are limited to using SMO for this because the .NET client `System.Data.SqlClient` will not accept that command as good syntax. It is strictly a terminator for SSMS and not true SQL syntax.

I in fact had the request for a client to handle the `GO` so you could do something like this:

```
$dbServer = MyServer
$ScriptDirectory = 'C:\scripts'
Import-Module SQLPS
$srv = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $dbServer

try {
 $file = dir $ScriptDirectory
 foreach ($f in $file) {
  $s = Get-Content $f -Raw
  $srv.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery($s);
 }
}
catch {
 $error[0].Exception
}
```

If you do not have to deal with the `GO` statement and want to use the .NET method [you can check out an article published on SQLShack](http://www.sqlshack.com/connecting-powershell-to-sql-server/). It walks you through how to make the connection and execute, and also touches a bit more on using PS with SQL Server.